# How much does pixel pitch of monitor matter when editing video/photos?

Tags: video, display, editing, photos, pixels

Is  0.27mm good enough?

Comment: You have to provide screen size and expected working resolution before anyone can give you an honest answer.

Comment: My 2p: depends on how far you are from the pixels, and how good the dithering is. 0.27mm should be good enough for graphics, but not for lots of close-up text work. For coding/etc, you probably want 0.2mm or better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1920x1200 24'' monitor, a dot pitch of 0.27mm is indeed expected. This give you roughly 94 pixels per inch. Picture is sharp and true (assuming you use the monitor correctly, of course. Meaning using the native resolution and correct refresh rate).

**How do you know?**

- Use this calculator:
  [Display Calculator](http://thirdculture.com/joel/shumi/computer/hardware/ppicalc.html).
  Input the data from your monitor
  size and native resolution.

The result will give you the most appropriate dot pitch. Variations happen among vendors. Anything within 0.05 mm range is acceptable and imperceptible even to the most trained eye.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel pitch is a function of your LCD monitor size.  i.e. it's the same for monitors of the same size.  LCD monitors only display at a single resolution — their native resolution. Images are best displayed at the native resolution of the monitor. If you choose a different resolution, the monitor will have to use interpolation, which reduces image quality.

Comment: Pixel pitch is a function of both the monitor size and the native resolution. Two monitors of the same size might have different native resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I JUST bought a 24" Dell U2410, 1920X1200 optimal res.

So basically any LCD monitor with the above specifications would have a pixel pitch of 0.27mm? Is that at all right?

Comment: Yes.  I think that's correct.  @A Dwarf below provided a link to a calculator.

Comment: @davr.  Thanks for keeping me honest.  Factors like pixel geometry are all things that might make for variations in pixel pitch, but as the question was "is .27 good enough' I was trying to not turn this into an engineering project ;-)

Comment: lol please feel free to turn the answer into an engineering project...I find (within limits) that it helps! I originally thought that pixel pitch had to do with pixel shape...which is why I asked what 0.27mm meant...
Thanks for mentioning that, DaveP!

Answer (score 0):

Pixel pitch does not matter much, but the higher the pitch, the better the contrast, brightness and viewing angles. 
But if you want to do photo and movie editing, panel type is much more important. I think in your case an IPS panel is best. Those panels have true 24 bit colour reproduction (TN panels use flickering/dithering techniques to achieve 24-bit like colour), acurate colour, great viewing angles, good contrast, yet are pretty fast in response. Have a look at the DELL U2410 or the HP LP2475W for example.